# argumentnullexception was unhandled by user code

Tags: asp.net, exception, null, argumentnullexception

In an ASP.NET application while uploading data from an excel sheet to website im getting the error

```
   System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
```

Source Error:

```
Line 161:                LHSupdate.Name = AssociateName;
Line 162:
Line 163:                var designation = dsData.Tables["LHS"].AsEnumerable().Where(r => Convert.ToString(r["Associate Id"]).Trim() == LHSupdate.AssciateID.Trim());
Line 164:
Line 165:                if (designation != null)
```

Source File: D:\GENIUS\LHS\LHS\UpdateLHS.aspx.cs    Line: 163

Stack Trace:

```
[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source]
   System.Data.DataTableExtensions.AsEnumerable(DataTable source) +34903
   LHS.Login.btnfileUplode_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\GENIUS\LHS\LHS\UpdateLHS.aspx.cs:163
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +118
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +112
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5563
```

What should i do to run succesfully.
Please advice further

Comment: `dsData.Tables["LHS"]` is apparently null. See to it that it isn't.

Comment: all the tables are having values. please help how to check this